# Umbraco get media from url

Tags: c#, url, media, umbraco

I want to protect my media by a genericHandler.ashx. I have a rewrite rule /media to /handlers/my-handler.ashx?media-url=xxx.jpg But I cannot find a function in umbraco api to get nodeId from url.

At the moment I use this sql query :

```
public static Int32 GetNodeIdFromUrl(String url)
{
        SqlParameter[] sqParams = { new SqlParameter("@url", url) };
        string sql = "select contentNodeId from cmsPropertyData where dataNvarchar =     @url";
        int id = -1;
        try
        {

           id = (int)SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(umbraco.GlobalSettings.DbDSN,CommandType.Text,sql,sqParams);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            umbraco.BusinessLogic.Log.Add(
                umbraco.BusinessLogic.LogTypes.Error, 
                new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0), 0,
                "Error from download security handler ->" + ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return id;
    }
```

inspired by http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/4284-getting-media-Id-from-path

do you know any umbraco api function to do this before ?

Answer (score 0):

i think if you know the correct format of the url, you can take the media id by using some regular expression or by splitting the url.

Comment: No there's no mediaId inside the url. /media/1042/xxx.jpg gives a cmsPropertyData.Id

Comment: Yes then you can take the property id 1042 from the url. By getting the property id you can take the media item.

Comment: @mahesh How exactly do you get the media item from the property id with the umbraco API ?

Comment: @marapet: Use **umbraco.library.GetMedia(mediaId)** to get the media item OR you can use **Media m = new Media(Convert.ToInt32(ImageID));
if (m != null && m.getProperty("umbracoFile") != null)                        {imagePath = m.getProperty("umbracoFile").Value.ToString();                     }**

Answer (score -1):

If you have a redirect set up to map anything from /media to /handlers/my-handler.ashx, then the original URL request will be in the format /media/{mediaID}/{fileName}.{extension}.
The media ID is the name of the folder inside the /media directory on disk. When you get an incoming request, simply SubString everything after "/media/" and before the next "/".

HTH,

Benjamin

Comment: No there's no mediaId inside the url. /media/1042/xxx.jpg gives a cmsPropertyData.Id. isn't it ?

Comment: Yohann, the way Umbraco works is by storing anything in the Media library under the /media folder, and using a subfolder to denote the media item's ID - in the form /media/{mediaID}/{myfilename}.{myextension}. If you are redirecting requests (in Regex form for UrlRewriting.Net - ^/media/(.*)+$) then your handler will be fed something like /1042/xxx.jpg. You want the "1042" part of the URL.

Comment: @codegecko That's not correct - as the OP correctly stated, _1042_ is the id of the `cmsPropertyData` table.